# UITableView cell auto height adjustment with image scaling issue iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView, which has a custom cell that I want to display a single image. I want the cell to automatically adjust the height according to the image's size. The UIImageView is filled in the cell, with auto layout constraints set on the four edges.

The images may be on different sizes, some are wider than the screen width. In such case, due to the content mode I set on the UIImageView, the image will be scaled to aspect fit the entire UIImageView.

When I set everything up and run, I realized that the UITableView didn't set the cell height correctly. It seemed that the image was scaled to fit the UIImageView but UITableView still set the cell height to be equal to the original image's height. Besides this issue, I also don't know why the image was scaled given that there are only 640 pixels on the width of the image and the iphone 6 simulator should have 750 pixels on the width ?

As summary, I have two questions here:

1. If I give an image with 640 pixels wide to an UIImageView that fills the entire width of the screen, why the image is scaled?
2. If the image is indeed scaled, how to let the UITableView automatically calculate the cell height based on the scaled size rather than the original size.

If possible, please use Swift instead of Objective-C for showing the code. Also you can assume I am using iOS 8+. Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, my images are preloaded to the project in the Assets and I put them as 1x images. So I think when xcode loads them in simulator, it doubles the pixels so the image doesn't fit to the screen and needs to be scaled? This may be the answer to my first question though I am not sure. I realized that when I moved the image to the 2x slot, it was not scaled anymore.

Comment: I tried to put image files to the project folder instead of putting them in the Assets. The purpose is to stop iOS doubling the pixels of the images but take the original resolution as it is. Then I load the image to UIImage with the full file name. Interestingly, after doing this, things work better in simulator where no pixel doubling happened. But when I run the app on iphone 6, the phone still tries to double the pixels for me. Any idea why this happens?